# parse & as part of variable in php

Tags: php

I have this:

```
mysite.com/index.php?refferer=http://www.refferersite.com/index.php?var1=a&var2=b
```

this

```
http://www.refferersite.com/index.php?var1=a&var2=b
```

Will become this:

```
http://www.refferersite.com/index.php?var1=a
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

you will need to [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) your input

Answer (score 1):

Use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) on the url.

The link will then become:

```
mysite.com/index.php?refferer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.refferersite.com%2Findex.php%3Fvar1%3Da%2a6var2%3Db
```

As you can see, the ampersands are escaped.